# How to show contents in a postgresql table

Tags: postgresql

I logged into my postgresql database in a cloud server, and I know that `\d` is used for showing all tables in my database, and `\d mytablename` is used for showing all columns in the table.

However, can anyone tell me how to show the contents of each column in the table?

I have tried to use `SELECT * FROM mytablename`, but it does not make any difference.

Comment: Does not make any difference from what? `SELECT * FROM mytablename` selects all the data from a table for sure.

Comment: I found out the reasons now. I did not add quotation marks for the tablename and did not add a semicolon in the end. Thank you.

Comment: I still have a question, zerkms. After creating the table, I used php to register users in my users form. However, it failed.
[link]function register($dbh, $user, $pw) {
 if(!dbh) {
  die('Could not connect to Postgresql:'. pg_last_error($dbh));
 }
 $query = 'INSERT INTO users ("username", "password") VALUES (user, pw)';
 $result = pg_query($query); // send the result to the database
 if($dbh -> result == TRUE) {
  echo "Register successfully\n";
 } else {
  error_log("Fail to register");
 }
 $dbh -> close();
}[link]
Here is my codes

Comment: Ask a proper question with formatted code.